# filter R data frame with one column - keep data frame format

Tags: r, dataframe

I am looking for a simple way to display a subset of a one column data frame
Let's assume, I have a a data frame:

```
> df <- data.frame(a = 1:100)
```

Now, I only need the first 10 rows. If I subset it by index, I'll get a result vector instead of a data frame:

```
> df[1:10,]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

I tried to use 'subset' but not using the 'subset'-parameter will result in an error (only for one-column-data-frames?):

```
subset(df[1:10,])
Error in subset.default(df[1:10, ]) : 
  argument "subset" is missing, with no default
```

There should be a very easy solution to achive a subset (still a data frame) filtered by row index, no?
I am lookung for a solution with basic R commands (it should not depend on any special library)

Comment: thanks a lot for the hint to this other quesrion! For some reason I could not find it by myself.

Answer (score 9):

you can use `drop=FALSE`, which prevent from droping the dimensions of the array.

```
df[1:10, , drop=FALSE]
    a
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
...
```

For `subset` you need to add a condition.